# How to force gem version in rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I need to use addressable 2.2.4 gem, but I have 2.2.5 version (because of an issue discussed here: https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable/pull/33). I tried:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
source 'http://gems.github.com'
gem "addresable", "2.2.4"

bundle install
```

and get `Could not find gem 'adressable (= 2.2.4, runtime)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.`

If I install/uninstall gem manually by

```
sudo gem install addressable -v 2.2.4
sudo gem uninstall addressable -v 2.2.5
```

I get the same error.

So, how can I force 2.2.4 version for my app?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. You've misspelled "addressable" in your gem line.
2. Your bundle might be locked at 2.2.5 — try running `bundle update`. It's counter-intuitive, but it'll rebuild your Gemfile.lock with the specified version.
3. You don't need gems.github.com as a source anymore — they quit building it and recommend rubygems.org.